# Can't add ModelMap to Session

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session

I want to share login message to another method, but don't know how. So I used

spring annotation `@SessionAttributes` in Controller, and try `addAttribute` to

save `user` to `ModelMap`. But when I used `@ModelAttribute` in another method,

my browser thrown: 
    `500 - Expected session attribute 'user'`

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class Login {
    @Resource
    private UserSer userSer;

    @RequestMapping("/main")
    @ResponseBody
    public String login (@RequestBody User user, ModelMap map) {
        boolean result = userSer.login(user);
        String view = "fail";

        if(result) {
            map.addAttribute("user", user);
            view = "success";
        }

        return view;
    }


        //It doesn't work
        @RequestMapping("/logout")
        public String logout(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
            System.out.println(user.getUsername());
            return "success";
        }

    }
```

Do I need to configure web.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove @ResponseBody from login method. When you use @ResponseBody, the return value is directly written to the response. Spring couldn't get time to create Session object and save to model attribute in this case.

Comment: It worked, but I need to add some code in `$.ajax`.  Can I use model attribute and `@ResponseBody`  in the same time?  Is it possible.

Comment: I didn't get your question. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: If I use`@ResponseBody` ,  can I save my `user` to Session object?

Comment: "@ResponseBody" and "@SessionAttributes" combination will not work. If you want to maintain session then use HttpSession or WebRequest parameter in your method. Please refer http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttributes.html